# SQL Server - Recursion starting from a specific tuple

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I came from the example here [[a link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674287/Recursive-Queries-in-Microsoft-SQL-Server)] that explains how to write a recursive query.

```
WITH security_menu_Recursive(Parent,MenuId,MenuName,LEVEL)
AS
(
    SELECT vparent,vmenuid,vmenuname,0 AS LEVEL FROM dbo.SecurityMenu WHERE vParent = null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT vparent,vmenuid,vmenuname,Level + 1 AS LEVEL FROM dbo.SecurityMenu
    INNER JOIN security_menu_Recursive AS smr ON smr.menuid = dbo.SecurityMenu.vParent
)
SELECT parent,menuid,menuname,LEVEL FROM security_menu_Recursive
```

This works for me as is, but I'm looking for starting recursion from a specific tuple, in the above example, starting from a MenuId of 102 for example.

I tried adding the condition `WHERE vmenuid = 102` in the three SELECTs but it didn't work.

Comment: Add the additional criteria to the anchor (the top `SELECT` in your example) to start from a specific spot.   If that doesn't provide the desired results we'll need more information to help.

Comment: Exactly @GoatCO. I can't yet upvate replies but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work well if you just replace the null check for the anchor with a vmenuid=102 condition;

```
WITH security_menu_Recursive(Parent,MenuId,MenuName,LEVEL)
AS
(
    SELECT vparent,vmenuid,vmenuname,0 AS LEVEL FROM dbo.SecurityMenu WHERE vMenuid=102
    UNION ALL
    SELECT vparent,vmenuid,vmenuname,Level + 1 AS LEVEL FROM dbo.SecurityMenu
    INNER JOIN security_menu_Recursive AS smr ON smr.menuid = dbo.SecurityMenu.vParent
)
SELECT parent,menuid,menuname,LEVEL FROM security_menu_Recursive
```